# Xcode - Remove Archive Option

Tags: ios, xcode, build, app-store, archive

In my Xcode project, I've two targets. One is for actual distribution of the app and the other one is for performance testing. Both are almost same but the later has some additional code for checking the performance.
 
For the target that is used for performance, I want to disable "Archive" option, so that by mistake it shouldn't be built for submission to App Store. Is it possible, if Yes, How?

Comment: I don't think you can disable the Archive option. By default In xcode it is there.

Comment: @DeepakKumarSahu Or else, is there any build script or attribute to be set to prevent archiving?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. Though I'm not sure. Keep trying. Good Luck.